# Binary Flags: How to check for "1 must have and 1 of n must haves"

Tags: bit-manipulation, flags

I have a flagable enumeration.

```
Flags
{
    None = 0
    A    = 1
    B    = 2
    C    = 4
    D    = 8
}
```

Than I have a condition where I must check if a variable `flags` is set with `Flags.A` and at least one of `Flags.B`, `Flags.C` or `Flags.D`.

The current and easiest approach is

```
if ( 
    ( flags == Flags.A | Flags.B )
    || ( flags == Flags.A | Flags.C )
    || ( flags == Flags.A | Flags.D )
)
{
}
```

I'm asking for an approach to check it in one condition with one bitwise operation without the several || operations.

Something like this one (I tried this without success)

```
if ( flags == Flags.A | ( Flags.B | Flags.C | Flags.D ) )
{
}
```

Comment: `flags & Flags.A && flags != Flags.A` ...? First part ensures `Flags.A` _is_ set, and second part ensures _something else_ must also be set (because otherwise, `flags == Flags.A` would be true.)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, *checking* if a flag is set in a value is done with `&` and not with `|`. Your checking with `==` won't work because that would mean *exact equality*  which is quite hard to achieve if you have 7 different possibilities that fulfill your condition.

Furthermore you condition is "*flag A is set **and** one of B, C **or** D*" so I don't see any possibility to do this check in a single bitwise operation, you will always need at least one logical operation

So it could be something like

```
if (flags & Flags.A && (flags & Flags.B || flags & Flags.C || flags && Flags.D))
```

which may be shortended to

```
if (flags & Flags.A && flags & (Flags.B | Flags.C | Flags.C))
```

Depending on the language you plan to use, there might be slight variations in the exact syntax ...

Comment: In my case the equality check is correct. I start with Flags.None, and with every call I pass the new flag and add it to the bitmask. And on every call of the same method I check if the bitmask is the mentioned case I'm asking to check more easily. In my case it's about asynchronous tasks which have to be completed for "one must have and one of a set of must haves".

Comment: So lets assume your `flags` variable has (as an integer) the value `7` ie is `A|B|C`. Then neiter of `flags == Flags.A | Flags.B` or `flags == Flags.A | Flags.C` will be true. So your current "working" approach will accept only flag registers that have `A` and *exactly one*  of `B`, `C`, or `D` set. This contradicts your question where you require *at least one*  of `B`, `C`, or `D` to be set

Comment: I don't know which of these two options you really need. My answer is based on what you have written as requirement (A + at least one of B, C, or D) in your question and on the code you show, which doesn't fulfill this requirement (A + exactly one of B, C or D)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm asking for an approach to check it in one condition with one bitwise operation without the several || operations

It's possible, here's an example in C#:

```
BitOperations.RotateRight(flags, 1) > 0x80000000
```

The principle behind this is that flag A is put into the most significant bit, so the numbers that have flag A set are greater than or equal to 0x80000000 (assuming you work with 32-bit unsigned integers), and the condition "at least one other flag is set" translates into the number having to be strictly greater than 0x80000000.

I have assumed that any bit other than the bits corresponding to A,B,C,D are zero, if that's not necessarily the case you can just zero out the other bits first: `flags & 15`.

In general, you can rearrange the bits somehow to put any "must have" flags near the top of the integer, and any "any of these" flags near the bottom of the integer, and then the condition will be `sortedFlags > allMustHaves`. Rearranging the bits can be tricky, unless you have access to [PEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.bmi2.x64.parallelbitextract?view=net-7.0) to extract-and-compress arbitrary subsets of bits, although it won't always be the best solution (in this example, the rotate should be better).

Comment: While that works, isn't it somehow defeating the purpose of having an enum? Ie, so that you don't have to care about the concrete values anymore but can just use the names.

Comment: @derpirscher Well yes. The version with PEXT can be written in terms of the flag names though.